# Changing page with php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to change the page when the user hits the login button. When the login button is hit currently the page just refreshed the user is not redirected to the new page. I created the session before any of the code for the page. I am wondering if it has to do with the location of my header command.

```
    <?php 
    session_start(); 
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <br>Name: <input type="text" name="NameTextBox"><br>
            <br>What grade are you currently in?: <input type="number" name="GradeTextBox"><br>
            <br><button name="Login" type="submit">Login</button></br>
        </form>

        <?php

            if (isset($_POST["Login"])) {
                $_SESSION["start"] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
                //echo "This session is beginning at ".$_SESSION["start"]."<br /><br />";
            }   

            if(isset($_POST["Login"])){
                if($NameTextBox = "Phydeaux"){
                    //echo"Good Name!";
                     PassLogin();
                }
                elseif($NameTextBox = "Rover"){
                    //echo"Good Name!"; 
                     PassLogin();
                }
                elseif($NameTextBox = "Spot"){
                    //echo"Good Name!";
                    PassLogin();                                         
                }
                else{
                    echo"You cannot login!";
                }

            }

            function PassLogin()
            {
                //print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
                //print 'alert("Running PassLogin Function")'; 
                //print '</script>';  

                $_SESSION["ReadingGrade"] = "Fail";
                $_SESSION["WritingGrade"] = "Fail";
                $_SESSION["MathGrade"] = "Fail";
                $_SESSION["Grade"] = $GradeTextBox;
                $_SESSION["Name"] = $NameTextBox;
                Header('Location: Reading.php');
            }

            if (isset($_POST["Login"])){
                //echo "Login has been pressed";
            }

        ?>  

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several synthax and technical problems with this code. In addition to [what AlexP said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823209/changing-page-with-php#19823358), you must observe that you cannot send the headers when you have already sent some output. The headers must be sent before any output, what is the same reason you had to put your `session_start()` in the beginning.

That being said, you should also make the login script before the HTML part, where your `session_start()` is, so your redirect header to `Reading.php` can work too. Or you can workaround that by placing a `ob_start()` in the beginning of the page, it will buffer the output preventing it from being sent before the script ends, this way you can call a `header()` wherever you like.

And talking about the header, the function is `header()`, not `Header()`. There is no native function named `Header()` in PHP. Function names are case sensitive.

In addition, you shouldn't use `action=""` in your `<form>`. Just suppress this attribute to make it post to the same page, it will make your code work don't matter what your php file name is. If you use `action=""` it will post to the `index.php` instead of `login.php`.

I also noticed you are using `Reading.php` (with capital letter) and `login.php`. I suggest you normalize all your file names to lower case, because if not you can have problems when porting this code to other systems. To Windows, Reading, reading, READING and ReAdInG are the same thing, to Linux it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the header information having already output your HTML. Move your HTML underneath the PHP header call.

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) says:

> header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP

Also, you are **assigning** the string value when you use `$NameTextBox = "Phydeaux"`, rather than conditionally checking it.

You should use the `==` double equals instead

```
if(isset($_POST["Login"])){
  $NameTextBox = $_POST['NameTextBox']; // $NameTextBox is now the posted value

  if($NameTextBox == "Phydeaux"){ // double equals checks the value of the variable
```

Comment: The JS runs if you uncomment the first three lines
I changed the code to this and still nothing:

function PassLogin()
   {
    //print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    //print 'alert("Running PassLogin Function")'; 
    //print '</script>';  
    
    $_SESSION["ReadingGrade"] = "Fail";
    $_SESSION["WritingGrade"] = "Fail";
    $_SESSION["MathGrade"] = "Fail";
    $_SESSION["Grade"] = htmlentities($_POST['GradeTextBox']);
    $_SESSION["Name"] = htmlentities($_POST['GradeTextBox']);
    Header('Location: Reading.php');
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Where will go your posts?

I will offer you this:

1- Write your PHP codes another page and named is "login.php"

2- Write your form action: `<form action="login.php" method="post">`